# Adding Ripple effect library

Tags: android

I have added the following library for ripple effect:
**https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple**

The problem is when i added them like this :

```
 <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/activity_txt"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activity_txt"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/activity_txt"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/activity_active_twin" />

    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

My layout gets disoriented. But in the sample code it works fine, can't figure out why?

Comment: why do you add external lib fo ripple effect. I think it is included in android sdk

Comment: for backward compatibility @Karacago

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the

```
android:layout_above="@+id/activity_txt"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activity_txt"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/activity_txt"
android:padding="2dp"
```

on the *com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout*

```
 <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/activity_txt"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activity_txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/activity_txt"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/activity_active_twin" />

 </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Comment: still not as the original one!

Comment: do you mean that the ripple effect doesn't show correctly?

Comment: ripple effect shows but i don't understand why is it disturbing my layout with the default attributes

Comment: could you please upload an image with the distribution? I can't understand what's happening.